# Get component by name In AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-components

I'm creating a ModalService in AngularJS 1.6.3 where I would like to pass the name of a component, which would then be displayed in a modal.

Note: I'm using ES2015.

Here is my component (where `template` is a simple html file, and `controller` is an empty class):

```
export default angular.module('editEntryModal', [])
    .component('editEntryModal', {
        restrict: 'E',
        bindings: {},
        template,
        controller
    })
    .name;
```

I then have a `ModalService` which has a `show` method. This is where I'm trying to get a reference to the above component:

```
class ModalService {
    constructor($injector) {
        this.$injector = $injector;
    }

    show(options) {
        // this.$injector.get(options.component)
    }
}
```

I've tried using `this.$injector.get(options.component)`, but it doesn't work. It throws an error `Unknown provider: editEntryModalProvider <- editEntryModal`

Here is where my `ModalService` is being called:

```
this.ModalService.show({
    component: 'editEntryModal'
})
```

Is there any way to get access to the component using its name?